# How to Present a DataTable in an MVC3 Razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a reliable and tested import method between an .xls spreadsheet[1] that returns a `DataTable`.  I've located this in my service layer, not data as only the workbook gets persisted as an uploaded file, but now I'm wondering where and how to produce an HTML representation of this `DataTable`.  I would prefer to avoid two loops in my view.  I have a variable number of columns in the `DataTable`.

[1] Using an OleDb interface.  I know it's archaic but it works.

Comment: what's the issue with using two loops? How about using `WebGrid` helper - however you need to generate column collection in some method based on input DataTable and supply to webgrid.

Comment: @VinayC, My issue is have too much Razor/C# in the view; I'm a perfectionist :-) 

Thanks for the tip on webGrid, I'm using Telerik as well, but a variable number of columns is a big concern for me.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Displaying-DataTables-in-Asp-Net-MVC-Razor-Page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DataTables are weakly typed. I hate weak typing.

Here's an alternative approach: using view models, strongly typed views and display templates. So start by defining a view model which will represent the information you are willing to display:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ColumnViewModel> Columns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RowViewModel> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RowViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CellValueViewModel> Values { get; set; }
}

public class CellValueViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

then you could have a controller action which will populate this view model. If you already have some service layers that spits DataTables, you could map those tables to the aforementioned view model. For the purpose of this demo let's hardcode:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Columns = new[] 
            { 
                new ColumnViewModel { Name = "column1" }, 
                new ColumnViewModel { Name = "column2" }, 
                new ColumnViewModel { Name = "column3" }, 
            },
            Rows = new[]
            {
                new RowViewModel 
                {
                    Values = new[] 
                    {
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "1x1" },
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "1x2" },
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "1x3" },
                    }
                },
                new RowViewModel 
                {
                    Values = new[] 
                    {
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "2x1" },
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "2x2" },
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "2x3" },
                    }
                },
                new RowViewModel 
                {
                    Values = new[] 
                    {
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "3x1" },
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "3x2" },
                        new CellValueViewModel { Value = "3x3" },
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and the last part is the view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Columns)
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Rows)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and our display templates:

`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/ColumnViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model ColumnViewModel
<th>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
</th>
```

`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/RowViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model RowViewModel
<tr>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Values)
</tr>
```

`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/CellValueViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model CellValueViewModel
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Value)
</td>
```

And that's pretty much all. As you can see we have written exactly zero loops in our views and we ended up with a nice `<table>` structure representing an Excel Worksheet.

Comment: Thanks very much Darin.  I had a disaster scenario, losing my working HD, and VS 2010 with it, but I will try this tomorrow, and looks like I will accept your answer.  They have always been good.

Comment: How to create a MyViewModel instance from a DataTable direclty?

Comment: @Southsouth, you could loop through the records in your DataTable and map them to your view model.

Comment: @Southsouth - we are doing just this on our project - looping through rows in datatable and transfer into model. This works, the only problem is that it is very slow. And idea how to make things work faster?