# Displaying VB table in HTML

Tags: vb.net, razor

I fear I am missing the obvious, but I have been unable to find how to display a Visual Basic DataTable object in a Razor View. Is there a way to change the row/column elements of the DataTable to the format required.

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012.

Thanks

Comment: That really is the problem. I cannot find anything that tells me what to do.  I have tried 
 @Html.DisplayFor(Function(Model) Model.mytable) which did not work.  I received a description of the table, but not the table.  Again, I am sure I am missing the obvious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Present a DataTable in an MVC3 Razor view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571034/how-to-present-a-datatable-in-an-mvc3-razor-view)

Comment: Thank you --- that looks like what I have spent hours looking for

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I've been doing MVC/Razor for one day.  Seems a lot less complicated than the linked solution from @dan-o

```
<table>
   @For Each row In Model.myDataTable.Rows
        @<tr>
            <td>@row("col1") </td>
             <td>@row("col2") </td>
        </tr>
   Next
</table>
```